# Asynchronous function got jammed when used inside while loop (scraperjs)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, web-scraping

I tried to make a scraper using ruipgil/scraperjs function that is asynchronous. But when I put it inside a loop, it got jammed and won't work. I'm new to Node and the idea of asynchronous programming so please bear with me.

So, I have this code:

```
let scraperjs = require('scraperjs');

// scraper function
function scrape(pageURI, callback) {
    console.log('checkpoint 2'); // checkpoint
    scraperjs.StaticScraper.create(pageURI).scrape(function($) {
        console.log('checkpoint 3'); // checkpoint
        return $("div").map(function() {
            return $(this).text();
        }).get();
    }).then(function(sometext) {
        callback(sometext);
    });
}

// loop function
function testloop() {
    let finished = false;
    let processed = false;

    while (!finished) {
        if (!processed) {
            console.log('checkpoint 1'); // checkpoint
            scrape('https://www.google.com/', (sometext) => {
                console.log('checkpoint 4', sometext); // checkpoint
                finished = true;
            });
            processed = true;
        }
    }
}

// non loop function
function testnonloop() {
    console.log('checkpoint 1'); // checkpoint
    scrape('https://www.google.com/', (sometext) => {
        console.log('checkpoint 4', sometext); // checkpoint
    });
}
```

I tried to dispatch both functions expecting a complete 4 checkpoints output. But strangely the one with loop got jammed in checkpoint 2 and never progresses. [I have also tried using promise instead of callback style, but still the same output.]

Where did I get wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the condition in the `while` loop will never change, because the callback function will never get executed.

That happens because JavaScript programs execute in an **Event Loop**. The JavaScript engine has a **Call Stack** (that records where in the program we are) and a **Callback Queue** (that keeps track of the asynchronous callbacks to execute).

The **Event Loop** monitors the **Call Stack** and the **Callback Queue**. If the call stack is empty, it will take the first event from the **Callback Queue** and will push it to the **Call Stack**, which runs it.

In your case the **Call Stack** never gets empty, it's always busy with the `while` loop, so the callback is never executed, so the `while` condition is always `true`.

A possible solution for you could be using `setTimeout` to call `scrape` until the first callback gets called. By using `setTimeout` you will free the **Call Stack**, letting the asynchronous calls execute.

```
// loop function
function testloop() {
    let finished = false;

    function loop () {
        if (!finished) {
            console.log('checkpoint 1'); // checkpoint
            scrape('https://www.google.com/', (sometext) => {
                console.log('checkpoint 4', sometext); // checkpoint
                finished = true;
            });
            setTimeout(loop, 0);
        }
    }
    loop();
}
```

You can find a more in depth explanation of the Event Loop here: [How JavaScript works: an overview of the engine, the runtime, and the call stack](https://blog.sessionstack.com/how-does-javascript-actually-work-part-1-b0bacc073cf)

Comment: so basically, "calling while terminator asynchronnously is bad" am I right? But what should I do if I want to run-then-erase a queue of asynchronous tasks until the queue is empty?

Comment: I updated my answer adding a sample that will let async code execute, while looping.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using recursion so that it doesn't get stuck in that while loop?

```
// loop function
function testloop() {
    console.log('checkpoint 1'); // checkpoint
    scrape('https://www.google.com/', (sometext) => {
        console.log('checkpoint 4', sometext); // checkpoint
        testLoop();
    });
}
```